# Change position of glov of CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change position of scroll glov from top to bottom of appBar inside of CustomScrollView. Accordingly to the sample from official docs, I could use NotificationListener. But when I try implement it in my code, notification.paintOffset doesn't defined. What should I do, here is my code:

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildContent(context),
    );
  }

 Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
  double leadingPaintOffset = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + AppBar().preferredSize.height;
  return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
    onNotification: (notification) {
      if (notification.leading) {
        notification.paintOffset = leadingPaintOffset;
      }
      return false;
    },
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(title: Text('Custom PaintOffset')),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            height: 100,
            child: Center(child: Text('Glow all day!')),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(child: FlutterLogo()),
      ],
    ),
  );

}
}
```

Here is exception:

```
The setter 'paintOffset' isn't defined for the class 'OverscrollIndicatorNotification'.
Try importing the library that defines 'paintOffset', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'paintOffset'.
```

So, notification.paintOffset doesn't defined! Please, help!
This is link to official doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html

Here is Flutter doctor output:

```
√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, ...)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

[image: ScrollView Glov sample image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to reprhase your question?

Comment: What exactly unclear in it?

Comment: Unfortunately, my English lang skills not so good))

Comment: Ok so the issue is, that the ```notification.paintOffset``` property is not being correctly set?

Comment: Yes... It isn't defined, when applying it in code!

Comment: The code you added to the question, works as expected, you might want to consider adding the rest of the code of the screen and posting a screenshot of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paintOffset` was introduced 3 months ago in [this commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/362a5573651f6fb7ab1e7e16b872de62ff1fea67)

You will not find it defined in previous flutter version (like yours v1.12.13). Try upgrading your flutter to at least 1.17.1 since it was merge on May 13, 2020

Comment: They didn't write anything about compatibilities of flutter versions..

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to update flutter version